# HighCharts - Pie Semi Circle (Arrow in Chart)

Tags: charts, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I've been trying to insert arrow in semi circle donut chart (like speedometer has)

tried everything but no result for me

this is it on image what I want to do

[image]

I have created jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/ to demonstrate my issue

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
  yAxis: [{
         min: 0,
         max: 90,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
         labels: {
          enabled: false
         },
            title: {
                text: '<div class="gaugeFooter">46% Rate</div>',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 80
            },
         plotBands: [{
          from: 0,
          to: 46,
          color: 'pink',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '0%'
         },{
          from: 46,
          to: 90,
          color: 'tan',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '0%'
         }],
         pane: 0,
         
     }],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            },
            gauge: {
       dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
       },
       dial: {
        radius: '100%'
       }
      }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   25],
                ['IE',       25],
                ['Chrome', 25],
                ['Opera',     25]
            ]
        }],
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two series - one for pie and another for angular gauge.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '75%'],
            size: '50%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 90,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '', //'<div class="gaugeFooter">46% Rate</div>',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 80
            },
            /*plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 46,
                color: 'pink',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            },{
                from: 46,
                to: 90,
                color: 'tan',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            }],*/
            pane: 0,

        }],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            },
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   25],
                ['IE',       25],
                ['Chrome', 25],
                ['Opera',     25]
            ]
        },{
            type: 'gauge',
            data: [40],
            dial: {
                rearLength: 0
            }
        }],
    });    
});
```

Comment: Hello, I just did according to you but getting some lines behind the arrow how can I remove these lines and also unable to change the colors when i paste the same code in jsfiddle its work but not in my website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879679/highchart-semi-pie-chart-with-arrow-issue please check for detail issue