# Highchart: Semi Pie chart with arrow issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using the highchart library for making chart in my website.
Facing issue:

1. In semi pie chart lines are showing behind the arrow, please see screen shot.
2. Unable to change the colors.

Code working in js-fiddle but not in my website.
Below is the code, please review and let me know if i miss something.

**Code**

```
$(function () {
                        Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '75%'],
            size: '50%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 90,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '', //'<div class="gaugeFooter">46% Rate</div>',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 80
            },
            /*plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 46,
                color: 'pink',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            },{
                from: 46,
                to: 90,
                color: 'tan',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '0%'
            }],*/
            pane: 0,

        }],
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            },
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
                name: 'Low',
                y: 35,
                color: 'Red' // Jane's color
            },
            {
                name: 'Medium',
                y: 30,
                color: 'Yellow' // Jane's color
            },
            {
                name: 'High',
                y: 35,
                color: 'Green' // Jane's color
            }                       


            ]
        },{
            type: 'gauge',
            data: [40],
            dial: {
                rearLength: 0
            }
        }],
    });
});
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Code working in js-fiddle but not in my website_ Then create an empty page on your website and try to disable all css and js except jQuery and highcharts

Comment: @Core972 thanks, ok let me try.

Comment: Hightcharts.css creating problem after disabling the file, work fine.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Problem solved.